# Scala code analyzer targets case variable names that are identical to the outer matched varables - "suspicous shadowing"

Tags: scala, analyzer

In the following code snippet in which the outer match vars (x,y) are case matched by (xx,yy):

```
scala> val (x,y) = (1,2)
x: Int = 1
y: Int = 2

scala> (x,y) match {
     |    case (xx:Int, yy:Int) =>  println(s"x=$x xx=$xx")
     | }
x=1 xx=1
```

We could have also written that code as follows:

```
scala> (x,y) match {
     |    case (x:Int, y:Int) =>  println(s"x=$x y=$y")
     | }
x=1 y=2
```

In this latter case the Scala Code Analyzers will inform us:

> Suspicious shadowing by a Variable Pattern

OK. But *is there any situation where we could end up actually misusing the inner variable (x or y) in place of the original outer match variables*?

It seems this is purely stylistic? No actual possibility for bugs?  If so i would be interested to learn what the bugs could be.

Comment: Variable shadowing is a lurking bug. A lurker is something that springs out and bites you when you have a) forgotten your code when you come back to it, or b) have someone new to the area come in and try to learn/maintain it. It's generally not worth the bother to leave the shadowing in place.

Comment: @BobDalgleish  I was asking for explicit demonstrations of how this "lurking bug" could manifest itself - not theoretical.

Comment: It isn't the least bit theoretical. I've been bit myself, but in a somewhat larger function. I couldn't figure out why the variable I was using wasn't showing the value I expected. Spent nearly an hour banging my head on the debugger until I noticed the shadow. Do everyone a favor and write clean code, please!

Comment: Perhaps the simplest example is `(y,x) match { case (x,y) => ... }`.  Types are fine, but x and y are swapped for the case -- an accident waiting to happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be confusing:

```
val x = Some(1)
val y = Some(2)

(x, y) match {
    case (Some(x), Some(y)) => println(s"x=$x y=$y")
}
```

`x` and `y` have different types depending on whether you are inside or outside of the `match`. If this code wasn't using simply `Option`, and was several lines longer, it could be rather difficult to reason about.

Could any bugs arise from this? None that I can think of that aren't horribly contrived. You could for example, mistake one for another.

```
val list = List(1,2,3)
list match {
    case x :: y :: list => list // List(3) and not List(1,2,3)
    case x :: list => list      // List with 1 element, should the outer list have size 2
    case _ => list              // Returns the outer list when empty
}
```

Not to mention what a horrible mess that is. Within the `match`, `list` sometimes refers to an inner symbol, and sometimes the outer `list`.

Answer (score 0):

It's just code that's unnecessarily complicated to read and understand, there are no special bugs that could happen.